# AuthorizeView Roles always return false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm testing Blazor WASN with individual account (Duende) and NetCore 7.

I create a new app, I add this to index.razor (client)

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using System.Security.Claims
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject NavigationManager Navigation


<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<AuthorizeView>
  <Authorized>
    USARIO AUTORIZADO
  </Authorized>
  <NotAuthorized>
    USARIO NO AUTORIZADO
  </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="admin">
  <Authorized>
    Admin OK
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="user">
  <Authorized>
    User OK
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="yo">
  <Authorized>
    Yo OK
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="user">
  <Authorized>
    User OK
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="yo, user">
    User y Yo Ok
  </AuthorizeView>
```

And this is my program.cs (server):

```
using Bl74.Server.Data;
using Bl74.Server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
  .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() //<--- PARA LOS ROLES
  .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>() //<--- PARA LOS ROLES
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
  app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
  app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
  }
else
  {
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
  // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
  app.UseHsts();
  }

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

I add to database a new AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles
When I run the app, I loggin with user, but alwayas doesn't work with this error:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
          Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
          RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (yo|user)
```

If I add [Authorize(Roles = "user")] to any page, the result is the same: I don't have permission to access

I think that I need add any config to program.cs, but I do not know what

Thnak you

I tried add any config server to program.cs, always the same

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (yo|user)
```

Comment: the code you provided shows that the user does not have the roles (yo|user). And i can't see the code where you assign roles. Did you add the roles to the user?

Comment: I addded the rol on database manually

Comment: I tried this "await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "user");" then register a new user. It's fail too

Comment: When the user logs in you have to query the roles from the database and store them somewhere so the app knows the roles of the user. typically in a token or a cookie. 
You could google for 'blazor webassembly role based authorization' to get started.

Comment: Thank you, I try, I read all about this in Microsoft, I have search in google, in bing, ... always the same

Answer (score 0):

Alter a week search, I have found this link:
[https://www.blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/2]

This program.cs work for me:

```
using BL06.Server.Data;
using BL06.Server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddSession();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
      .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
               .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
                 options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                 options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
               });
// Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler
    .DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();//para usuario


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
  app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
  app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
  }
else
  {
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
  // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
  app.UseHsts();
  }

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```